# ~/.ssh/rc is not executed when using ssh

Tags: bash, ssh, zsh

I'm in the situation of having to connect to various systems via `ssh` to do some quick work and then leave without a trace. Before I do any work, however, I would like to set up some aliases to save time, aliases that don't persist after my session is terminated.

Given the nature of the unknown environments, I want to avoid relying on `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc` since I don't want to check for, copy, parse, or in any way handle existing files beyond what's absolutely necessary for the work I'm doing.

Ideally, I should be able to add commands to be executed before my `ssh` login prompt inside `~/.ssh/rc`, but I can't get `ssh` to execute the file when I make a connection.

I've made sure to enable the `PermitUserRC` option inside `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`.

Both `.ssh/` and `.ssh/rc` have permissions set to `700`.

How can I get `ssh` to execute `~/.ssh/rc`?

I'm on MacOS Catalina 10.15.7 running `zsh` 5.7.1 inside Terminal 2.10.

Comment: You have `~/.ssh/rc` set up on the target machine (the one you log in to) I assume. Usually running `ssh -vv` gives diagnostic output which could help (try more v to get more output).

Comment: `ssh -vvvv` doesn't seem to produce any smoking gun. It's all on the target machine, but if I can launch a normal interactive session on the tail end of an ssh command, a session with any motd, a prompt, and no surprises down the line, that would be an acceptable workaround. I'll look into that.

Comment: Ah, `PermitUserRC` must be set in `sshd_config`, not in `ssh_config`. But the default (at least on macOS) is "enabled" so it shouldn't matter.

Comment: Good catch, but the option wasn't disabled in `sshd_config` either. I've ended up spawning a bash shell and supplying it with a temporary rc file by using bash's `--rcfile`. Unfortunately, zsh doesn't seem to have an equivalent option.